# Compiling C code with external library references

Tags: c, linux, join, compiler-errors

I am on RHEL 6.0 and got hold of the source code for `join` command(hopefully from the right source!!). I rarely work on a C code and hence finding this  difficult. I am trying to compile and run the C code for `join`, but running into compile time errors.

```
g++ join.c
join.c:19:20: error: config.h: No such file or directory
join.c:25:20: error: system.h: No such file or directory
join.c:27:25: error: hard-locale.h: No such file or directory
join.c:28:24: error: linebuffer.h: No such file or directory
join.c:29:24: error: memcasecmp.h: No such file or directory
join.c:30:19: error: quote.h: No such file or directory
join.c:31:21: error: stdio--.h: No such file or directory
join.c:32:22: error: xmemcoll.h: No such file or directory
join.c:33:21: error: xstrtol.h: No such file or directory
join.c:34:22: error: argmatch.h: No such file or directory
```

Since I am not aware of where to find these libraries(I did google for each one and they are spread all over different websites), can anyone please guide me as to how I can link these libraries together and compile the source code of `join` command?

Comment: Please take time to learn more how to use GCC and the `g++` command. Also, take the habit of compiling with `g++ -Wall -g` (and the other options, e.g. `-I` *include-directory* needed). Learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. The `join` source probably has a `README` or `INSTALL` file and uses `configure` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a linking problem as you suggest.  Instead, you get these errors because `g++` can't find these files: `config.h`, `system.h`, ..., that are `#include`d (indirectly) by `join.c`.

What you could do is `find` these files on your system, and then add as many `-I<directory>` options behind the `g++` as there were directories you found these files in.  Do `man g++` for more info.

You'll also need to find the where the libraries are you need to link against.  So you'll need to specify more than `-I`'s.

On the other hand, aren't there 'configure' or other package files?  Normally you don't have to specify compiler flags (like this `-I`) by hand.  Instead, it's common that for example Makefile's are generated from such a configuration file, after which you just have to type `make`.

I advise you to get someone that has done this before, because you don't seem to understand the basics of C program compilation. This can cost you a lot of your precious time without results. But good luck anyway!

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you don't have everything in place to compile your code. Try installing the `build-essential` package.

```
sudo yum install build-essential
```

On a relevant note, I'm not aware of the script join.c but if you are looking for a way to concatenate a bunch of files together, you can do `cat FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 > BIG_FILE` where `FILE1` `FILE2` `FILE3` are the files you want to join them. Under RHEL 6.0, you can use asterisks too, if there is a pattern. For example, `cat FILE.00* > BIG_FILE`

Comment: This is not at all relevant to the question.